# Understanding macro functions in C that define variables

Tags: c, macros

From my understanding, preprocessor directives are used to modify source code before its compiled. I'm writing some code of an assignment, but my macro causes errors. In my assignment I have to write several files with main() with identical variables. I want to use macros like this.

```
#define SETUP (i)\
     char* memory = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(i));\
     char* memory2 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(i))
#define CLOSE ()\
     free(memory);\
     free(memory2)

int main () {
     int i = 7;
     SETUP(i);

/****************************/
Do stuff with memory and memory2
/*****************************/

     CLOSE();
}
```

this way I can make changes to the beginning and end of each file's main() without having to change each one. Can someone tell me what I don't understand?

Comment: `but my macro causes errors`..what are those?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In your `main` function, do you have a declaration for `i` ***before*** the invocation of `SETUP(i)`?

Comment: `(char*) memory = ...` looks pretty invalid. Don't really remember if such a declarator is valid, but I'd start with that.

Comment: sorry, I fixed my post

Comment: The macros themselves are ok but you never declare variables `memory` and `memory2` anywhere. Start by writing the correct code without any macros.

Comment: `(char *) memory` is not an _lvalue_ so cannot be assigned to. Perhaps you meant `char * memory`?

Comment: You keep editing the code, which invalidates the comments and answers. Is it working now?

Comment: no, it's not. The code I wrote was just an example, I added my actual code

Comment: One other thing - if your code uses `malloc()` and `free()`, it is necessary to `#include <stdlib.h>` - without that, the casts on `malloc()` mask a programming error.    Then, unless your C compiler is actually a C++ compiler, the `(char *)` casts of `malloc()` are not required.

Comment: I recommend that you read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).  And note that `sizeof` is specified in units of `char`, so `sizeof (char)` must necessarily be 1, making that a redundant multiplication.  Also, look into the `do {...} while (0)` idiom for multi-statement macros - that may well save your bacon when you put cleanup in the error-handling).

Answer (score 4):

In the macro definitions, you have added a space between the macro name and opening parenthesis:

```
#define SETUP (args_needed)\
```

That defines an ordinary macro rather than a macro that takes parameters. Therefore `args_needed` is not a macro parameter and is not defined.

Remove the space between the macro name and opening parenthesis:

```
#define SETUP(args_needed)\
```

It is OK to insert a space when invoking the macro:

```
SETUP (10);
```

but that is considered poor coding style by many.

Comment: thanks so much, that fixed it. I didn't know white space mattered haha

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare `i` anywhere. `SETUP(i);` just passes `i` for the macro parameter `i`, so the code that the macro expands to contains an undeclared `i`. You probably want something like `SETUP(10);` instead.

Also this here

```
(char*) memory
```

Isn't how you declare a variable. This is a typecast, and it fails because `memory` is undefined. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: sorry, I added my actual code. I was sloppy when I wrote an example